# What's the difference between 退屈 and 飽きる?

Tags: questions

What's the difference between 退屈 and 飽きる

Comment: You cannot compare a noun to a verb.

Comment: 退屈する is a verb.

Comment: @Perico You are correct, but 退屈 on its own is just a noun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 退屈｛たいくつ}(する） to be boring
- 飽｛あ｝きる to be come tired of

There certainly is some overlap but not everything that is boring has one become tired of (some things are inherently boring) and not all things that one has become tired of are necessarily boring.